# How to import a PowerShell module for administrators only?

Tags: powershell, import-module

When importing a PowerShell module that

```bsh
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

from my PowerShell profile, it throws an `ScriptRequiresElevation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand` error.

How can I either

- a) add a condition/parameter that the module is only imported when running an elevated shell or
- b) move the import to a profile that gets only loaded when running an elevated shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to add the condition check in your profile script, you can add the check to see if you are running as Administrator:

```
$currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
if($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
{
    Import-Module NeedsAdminModule
}
```